# Upgrading Worklight 6.2 to MobileFirst Platform 7.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We are using Worklight enterprise 6.2 with fix packs and we are planning to upgrade to 6.3 in the next month (beginning of May 2015). However, we see now that IBM is about to release MFP 7.

Can you please clarify to me those queries:

1. What is the impact on the project which has been developed on version 6.2 to be moved to 6.3 or 7?
2. What is the recommendation for us in terms of upgrading, should we go immediately to WL7 or to 6.3 first?
3. We are very close to the production and our concern that the WL7 "might" be unstable or contains issues that we might face in a critical time."Feedback would be appreciated"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0 is not about to be released - [it is already released](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/03/20/ibm-mobilefirst-platform-foundation-v7-0/).
2. Lots of changes in both 6.3 and 7.0. Read the documentation to see what's changed...

   - 6.3: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/start/c_release_notes.html
   - 7.0: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/start/c_release_notes.html

In terms of your project structure, starting 6.3 the [adapter thread pool has been removed](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2014/12/22/adapter-thread-pools-removed/) and you are now in complete control of it. Your adapter XML will be upgraded to the new structure.

In terms of technology, starting 7.0 there is REST support together with a new authentication mechanism - OAuth. Classic authentication is as before and is still there. There are also now Java adapters in addition to JavaScript adapters, [and lots more](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/03/20/ibm-mobilefirst-platform-foundation-v7-0/).

7.0 is indeed new, but provides you with a lot of new possibilities.
6.3 is very stable (that is not to say that 7.0 is not stable, but it's also very new).

We cannot decide for you if to upgrade or not, it sounds like you are already considering the right things to consider.

Read about the two releases.

Comment: Thanks a lot Idan for the sufficient information. We will upgrade to 6.3 first since we believe it is the correct approach and I will go through the MFP 6.3 release note to get a full clarity on the new features.