# Upgrade project from WorkLight 6.2 to MobileFirst 7.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server, mobilefirst-server

I am using Worklight **6.2** and we are planning to migrate to **7.1**.

Some of my queries:

1) What need to change in the project files which has been developed on version 6.2 and how to do this?

2) What Server side changes have to do?

Appreciate if anyone can provide me the proper way to upgrade WorkLight Project & Server 6.2 to MobileFirst 7.1
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upgrade project from WorkLight 6.1 to MobileFirst 7.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34034065/upgrade-project-from-worklight-6-1-to-mobilefirst-7-1)

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499781/upgrading-worklight-6-2-to-mobilefirst-platform-7-0

Answer (score 1):

These are very generic questions and they very much depend on how and what did you implement in your project.

Note that there is an automatic migration tool, so I suggest that you will first import your project to MobileFirst Studio 7.1 and try to run your project. That's the first step in ensuring proper migration.

You should then review what has changed since 6.2, so read the 6.3, 7.0 and 7.1 What's New documents to get a better understanding:

- 6.3: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/start/c_release_notes.html
- 7.0: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/start/c_release_notes.html
- 7.1: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/start/c_release_notes.html

Answer (score 0):

Please find the documentation for the Migration of Worklight Project to 7.1 https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/devenv/c_migrating_projects.html?lang=en